# В чем ограничения дизайна предложенной архитектуры?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Дан абстрактный класс `Employee`, у него есть абстрактный метод `double salary();` Существуют 2 конкретных наследника `FullTimeEmployee` и `PartTimeEmployee`,  различаются по способу вычисления ЗП.

Какие ограничения данного дизайна? Как бы развивалась программа по управлению персоналом, используя данную иерархию?Спасибо если кто подскажет.

Comment: Вас интересует реальная проблема разработки HRM-решения в российских реалиях или сферический учебный пример?

Comment: Скорее сферический учебный пример

Comment: Перевод с одного вида работы на другую потребует удалять старый класс, создавать новый. Начислять зарплату должен не сам работник себе, а расчётчик. Наверное лучше сделать разные классы расчёта ЗП и назначать их Employee через поле какое-нибудь.

Comment: Т.е Вы предлагаете что-то вроде паттерна "Стратегия"? Когда к примеру класс FullTimeEmployee релизует некий интерфейс с контрактом double salary(); а в классе Employee вставляем через композицию данный интерфейс? Я вот о таком думал, но не знаю на сколько правильно так будет поступить...

Answer (score 1):

Не могу еще комментировать... Совершенно верно, логику подсчета необходимо вынести из класса "`Сотрудник`", вот [пример](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) на основе стратегии.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.